# iOS: Load PNG from disk, add PixelPerMeter properties to it, and save it to the Photo Album

Tags: objective-c, ios, png, dpi

Apparently with CGImages you can add kCGImagePropertyPNGXPixelsPerMeter and kCGImagePropertyPNGYPixelsPerMeter properties to the image and they will get added to the pHYs chunk of the png.  But UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum doesn't directly accept a CGImage.

I've been trying to load the image as a UIImage, then create a CGImage from that, add the properties, and then create a new UIImage from that data and saving that to the photo album.

An image is getting written to the photo album, but without the PPM settings. I can verify this in the preview app on MacOS, or using ImageMagick's `identify`.

ObjC isn't my domain, so here's what I've cobbled together from similar stackoverflow questions.

```
UIImage *uiImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];

NSDictionary* properties = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               [NSNumber numberWithInt:5905], (NSString *)kCGImagePropertyPNGXPixelsPerMeter, /* this doesn't work */
                               [NSNumber numberWithInt:5905], (NSString *)kCGImagePropertyPNGYPixelsPerMeter, /* this doesn't work */
                                @"This works when saved to disk.", (NSString *)kCGImagePropertyPNGDescription,
                               nil],(NSString*) kCGImagePropertyPNGDictionary,
                            nil];

NSMutableData* imageData = [NSMutableData data];
CGImageDestinationRef imageDest =  CGImageDestinationCreateWithData((CFMutableDataRef) imageData, kUTTypePNG, 1, NULL);

CGImageDestinationAddImage(imageDest, uiImage.CGImage, (CFDictionaryRef) properties);
CGImageDestinationSetProperties(imageDest, (CFDictionaryRef) properties); /* I'm setting the properties twice because I was going crazy */
CGImageDestinationFinalize(imageDest);

UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum( [UIImage imageWithData:imageData], nil, NULL, NULL );

// This is a test to see if the data is getting stored at all.
CGImageDestinationRef diskDest = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL(
    (CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.dpi.png",path]], kUTTypePNG, 1, NULL);

CGImageDestinationAddImage(diskDest, uiImage.CGImage, (CFDictionaryRef) properties);
CGImageDestinationSetProperties(diskDest, (CFDictionaryRef) properties);
CGImageDestinationFinalize(diskDest);
```

Updated: Revised and simplified the code a bit.  Still saves image to photo album and disk, but the pixels per meter value is not saving.  The description block gets saved to disk, but appears to get stripped when written to the photo album.

Update 2: By saving the file as a jpeg and adding TIFF X/Y Resolution tags to it I've been able to get the version saved to disk to store a PPI value other than 72.  This information is still stripped off when saving to the photo album.

Comparing a photo taken via iOS Camera app, one taken via Instagram, and one saved by my code, I noticed that the Camera app version has a ton of TIFF/EXIF tags, and the Instagram and my one have the same limited set of tags. This leads me to the conclusion that iOS strips these tags intentionally.  A definitive answer would help me sleep at night though.

Comment: Have you tried pulling the image back to check its properties? Maybe the function sets the value, but doesn't properly apply the changes. Everything you have looks okay. You have a lot of casting occurring, so it may be a compatibility issue with the different object types and it isn't able to actually set the properties. I can't say for sure, since I've only been looking at `CGImageDestination`s since I saw your question.

Comment: I just tried saving the image to disk using CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL, and that doesn't have PPM set either. So there must be something wrong with how I'm applying the properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is don't use UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum.

There's an ALAssetsLibrary method 
[writeImageDataToSavedPhotosAlbum: metadata: completionBlock:]

The metadata is a dictionary in the same format as the one passed to CGImageDestinationSetProperties.  PNG and JFIF density settings may be broken, I'm using kCGImagePropertyTIFFXResolution.